# Hadoop cluster capacity planning and determine the cluster size?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, bigdata

I have 10 name node, 200 datanodes, 10 seconder namenode , 1 job tracker, what is my cluster size and with configuration?

Comment: You can't have 10 namenodes in one cluster

Comment: Is it a HA cluster? What do you mean by "cluster size and with configuration"?